# What does Blood Moon Rising have to offer?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have been trying to find out what things are in the Blood Moon Rising mod, but can't seem to find anything. Can someone help me?

Comment: Just go look at the nexus page for it. It has a long description of everything it changes and multiple videos reviewing and showing it off.

Comment: I came here expecting this to be about Terraria

Answer (score 2):

Blood Moon Rising overhauls the werewolf system, with new perks and abilities for use.

In case you don't know, you can become a werewolf through the Companions questline, in Whiterun.